# How to solve this programming contest exercise

Tags: algorithm

I stumbled upon this algorithm question, I couldn't get any better approach than brute force, can someone guide me please?

> Given a M * N grid of characters (A,B). You are allowed to flip any
>   number of columns i.e. change A to B and B to A. What is the max
>   number of rows that can have same symbols after all possible flipping

Eg,

```
A B A|
B A B|
A B B|
B B A|
```

The answer is 2, if we flip both column 1 & 3. Please let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: In the example, there are 4 rows, but the solution is 2?

Comment: Use dynamic programming. @PieterGeerkens: how would you flip in the example to achieve four rows of identical symbols each?

Comment: @G.Bach I tried approach of DP but can't understand what recurrence relationship can be used, would be be column wise or row wise?

Comment: Column-wise since you flip columns. The optimality criterion are rows, though.

Comment: But I need more information than just the max score of (n-1) columns and their position. Can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: @G.Bach can you put it as an answer and explain a bit? I would like to know how to solve it better than O(m*n).

Comment: @Kent I'm not sure it would be better than O(mn), but it would be way better than brute force (which would be O(mn*2^n) if n is the number of columns). I'm not sure I should post an answer since Naman said it's a contest question.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I don't understand what you're saying; the question is quite clear: given a matrix, find the maximum number of rows that can be made all identical symbols by flipping an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: If this is about the maximum number of rows of just one character achievable by column-wise flipping, can't we just normalize on first column by flipping rows starting with `B`, and determine max #of identical rows, e.g., count after sorting? For M = #rows, this should take O(NMlog(M)) time.  
(In the example, it would seem flipping column 2 was sufficient)

Comment: Are there any more test-cases for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `A B A` and `B A B` are essentially the same for the purposes of this problem: whenever one gets flipped to all `A`s, the other gets flipped to all `B`s, and vice versa, so both count for the answer at the same time.
On the other hand, when `A B A` or `B A B` is flipped so that it contains the same letters, all other possible rows contain different letters.

So, the first suggested step would be to flip all *rows* which start with a `B`, since it will merge the pairs of rows which count for the answer at the same time.

Now, we have

```
A B A|
A B A|  (flipped from B A B)
A B B|
A A B|  (flipped from B B A)
```

What's left is to find a row that occurs most often.
This can be done by constructing a map which, well, maps rows to the number of their occurrences.
For the example, it will look like {`A B A`: 2, `A B B`: 1, `A A B`: 1}`.

Now, `A B A` obviously wins since it occurs twice, so we flip all the columns with `B`s in that row. Flipping all the columns with `A`s is another option.

Comment: This is a better solution than previously accepted solution. It is O(MN)

Answer (score 1):

I have an `O(n^2)` and `O(M)` solution but slightly better than bruteforce since the second loop starts to the `i+1` of the first loop, tell me what do you think about it :

First we need to change the A, B matrix for a bit matrix where each line will be a binary your matrix becomes :

```
0 1 0|
1 0 1|
0 1 1|
1 1 0|
```

now this is based on the fact that bitwise "010 & 101 = 000" so if there is a possible column permutation that will make the rows matched.

```
Given N and M;
int maxSameSymbole[M] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < M; j++) {
         if (!(line[i].toBinary & line[j].toBinary)) //this will equal 0 if there is a possible flip that will make the 2 rows with the same symbole
             maxSameSymbole[i]++;
    }
}

// Simple find max in the maxSameSymbole list :
int max = maxSameSymbole[0];
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    if (maxSameSymbole[i] > max)
        max = maxSameSymbole[i];
}
```

Hope this helped to find a better solution.

Comment: Sorry for late responding, but I realized that this algorithm is O(NM^2). Since even the boolean checking condition will take O(N) time. Can you please suggest some better method also? since the problem constraints were M<10000 and N<500

Answer (score 1):

Start from the first column and get the indices of the rows that would have same symbols if you flipped that column. for example: (1,4,9) rows work. Get those indices for every column and put them as the keys in a map that maps list of indices to a number it occurred. Highest value would be the answer.